# Find values in NSArray having NSArray with NSString using NSPredicate iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nspredicate

With `NSArray` only i can find values as:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"299-1-1", @"299-2-1", @"299-3-1", @"399-1-1", @"399-2-1", @"399-3-1", @"499-1-1", @"499-2-1", @"499-3-1", nil];
NSString *search = @"299";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", search]];
NSArray *array = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
NSLog(@"result: %@", array);
```

`Found Result` as expected :

```
 result: (
 "299-1-1",
 "299-2-1",
 "299-3-1"
 )
```

But for `NSArray` having `NSArray` with `NSString`

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"299-1-1", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"399-1-1", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"499-1-1", nil], nil];
```

What will be `predicate syntax` here?????

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To search in a nested array, you can use the "ANY" operator in the predicate:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"299-1-1", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"399-1-1", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"499-1-1", nil], nil];
NSString *search = @"299";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF CONTAINS %@", search];
NSArray *array = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
NSLog(@"result: %@", array);
```

Output:

```
(
    (
        "299-1-1"
    )
)
```

Comment: @Martin I was wondering if this can be done using subquery ? any insight ?

Comment: @Jennis: Yes, but why? Subqueries are more complicated and less effective, so I would use them only if there is no other solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i have a question related to your answer that is what is the theory of "ANY SELF"? please explain it for more clearance

Answer (score 4):

If you want to provide an array of searchTerms then you'll need to change your predicate.

Something like this would do it

```
NSArray *arr         = @[ @"299-1-1", @"299-2-1", @"299-3-1", @"399-1-1", @"399-2-1", @"399-3-1", @"499-1-1", @"499-2-1", @"499-3-1" ];
NSArray *searchTerms = @[ @"299", @"399" ];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^ (id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {   
  for (NSString *searchTerm in searchTerms) {
    if (NSNotFound != [evaluatedObject rangeOfString:searchTerm].location) {
      return YES;
    }   
  }
  return NO;
}];

NSArray *array = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"result: %@", array);
//#=> result: (
  "299-1-1",
  "299-2-1",
  "299-3-1",
  "399-1-1",
  "399-2-1",
  "399-3-1"
)
```

Comment: will work with [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", search]]

Comment: @Prince seriously? `not working???` - what could I possibly do to resolve your issue with that feedback?

Comment: did u get my question or not as i talking about nsarray in nsarray?

Comment: @Prince did you tried his solution ? it is working as per your requirement.

Comment: i m having structured data nsarray with nsarray as ( (),(),) not simply nsarray (,,,,). it will work for nsarray but my requirement is different.

Comment: Is generally better to put an actual example of your requirements and then it's harder to misinterpret, like 90% of the other answers

Comment: @AKB point me to the question you have made and I'll answer - there is no gain for anyone else in burying subquestions in comments

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"299-1-1", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"399-1-1", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"499-1-1", nil], nil];
NSString *search = @"299";
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSArray *array in arr) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS %@",search];
    if([array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count)
    {
        [filteredArray addObject:[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
```

Comment: This would not work as it looks like the OP is wanting to use `contains` to search for a substring. Your implementation checks whether the whole string is included in the collection - so each search term would need to be the full correct string for anything to match

Comment: The only way is to use loop i guys? if you find any other than do let me know!